ExpiresByType directive for image/avif not working
I have the following in my .htaccess file:
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"

ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/avif "access plus 1 year"

and so on...

I added the line ExpiresByType image/avif "access plus 1 year" to cover avif files just like jpeg type, but this directive seems not to work. Pagespeed says an avif file has only 7 days in the cache. Other files are well handled. Could you explain that?

Please include the complete HTTP response headers for such a request and add these to your question.

Do you have defined such MIME type image/avif?

Yes, it seems this is the answer. I added image/avif in cPanel/User Defined MIME Types. Looks like it was something new to my hosting. Now Pagespeed is happy.

In that case, looking at the HTTP response headers (the first step to diagnosing most caching issues) would have shown an inconsistency in mime-type's.

Looking at registered MIME types at my hosting company I found the missing avif type.
So I manually added at cPanel/MIME Types/User Defined MIME Types image/avif with extension avif. That's all.
